# SOOO close to a really clean solution to Question 6 from the 1988 Math Olympiad

Tags: contest-math, prime-factorization

I recently came across the "infamous" Question 6 after watching [this youtube video by Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y30VF3cSIYQ). Just to refresh everyone's memory, here it is:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $ab + 1$ divides $a^2 + b^2$. Show that
>  $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$$ is the square of an integer.

Being ever the optimist, I took out a pen and paper and got to a very simple solution in less than 30 minutes. With all this hoo-hah about this problem, I assumed my solution is probably wrong, so I decided to upload here. As soon as I began to write it in a more orderly fashion, I realized I have a missing step :(

I still think this approach is very elegant (a lot more than those Vietta jumps which are basically a Deux Ex-Machina solution imo). I'm hoping someone here can fill in the missing piece?

> **My proof:**
>  Let $c$ be the quotient which results from the division: $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}=c$$
>   Moving the denominator to RHS we get:
>   $$a^2+b^2=abc+c$$
>   Using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic we write every term in the [canonical representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic#Canonical_representation_of_a_positive_integer) - as a unique product of powers of primes, where ${p_i}$ are the prime numbers:
>   $$\left(\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i^{a_i}\right)^2
> +\left(\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i^{b_i}\right)^2=
> \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i^{a_i}\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i^{b_i}\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i^{c_i}+\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i^{c_i}
> $$
>   It follows that:
>   $$\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i^{2a_i}
> +\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i^{2b_i}=
> \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i^{{a_i}+{b_i}+{c_i}}+\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i^{c_i}
> $$
>
> We shall now show that for every $i$, $c_i$ is even
>
> 1. For every $i$ where $a_i \neq b_i$
>      We shall examine the [p-adic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) ${\nu_p}_i$ of both sides, where ${\nu_p}_i$ is defined to be the highest integer power such that the expression is divisible by ${p_i}^{{\nu_p}_i}$.
>      Note that at least one of $a_i,b_i$ in nonzero. From RHS we see that ${\nu_p}_i$ is exactly $c_i$ (if it were larger by 1, second term would become a fraction while left term remains an integer, so the sum would be a fraction)
>      From LHS by using the same exact consideration we see that ${\nu_p}_i$ is $\min(2a_i,2b_i)$.
>    In this case ${\nu_p}_i$ and hence $c_i$ is even.
> 2. For every $i$ where $a_i = b_i$
>      **This is where I'm stuck! I want to show that $c_i$ is even. So much trickier than I thought!**
>
> From (1) and (2) we see that $c_i$ is even for every i, hence:
>   $$\sqrt{c}=\sqrt{\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i^{c_i}}=\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i^{\frac{c_i}{2}}\in \mathbb{N}$$
>   QED???

Can someone help fill-in the gap?

Comment: If $a_i=b_i$ the LHS is divisible by $p_i ^{2 a_i}$ , hence the RHS is also divisible by it the term $p_i ^{a_i + b_i + c_i} = p_i ^{2 a_i +c_i}$ which is divisible by $p_i ^{2a_i}$ thus   $p_i ^{c_i}$ is divisible by it and we are done

Comment: I agree that ${p_i}^{c_i}$ is divisible by ${p_i}^{2a_i}$. This would imply that $c_i>=2a_i$ but I don't think that means $c_i$ is necessarily even.

Comment: Am thinking about your first case Why you assumed one of $a_i , b_i$ is non zero? That means each prime is contained in either A or B

Comment: The first case is more complicated ,Some primes may divide $a^2+b^2$ which are not in $a$ or $b$

Comment: $a_i$ and $b_i$ are always non-negative integers (that's how the prime decomposition works). If they are not identical, they can't both be zero. Hence one of them is positive.

Comment: @Ameryr, regarding your statement that some primes which divide $a^2+b^2$ might not be in $a$ or $b$ - that statement is definitely true.
In this specific case, however, we show that a specific divisor, ${p_i}^{\nu_i}$ definitely divides $a^2+b^2$, while showing that another divisor, ${p_i}^{{\nu_i}+1}$ definitely divides exactly one of $a^2$ or $b^2$, which means it definitely does not divide $a^2+b^2$ (because we are left with a fraction plus an integer).
So I do thinks it is true that $\nu_i$ is $\min{2a_i,2b_i}$.

Comment: Search "IMO 1988" and "1988 olympiad" for many occurrences of this problem in Math.StackExchange and MathOverflow. (This question may not be a "duplicate", *per se*, as it asks about a particular solution approach.)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is flawed from the very beginning. I assume your product is ranging over all possible prime numbers because of the infinite product notation. In that case, your claim that both $a_i$ and $b_i$ cannot be zero is trivially false.

$a,b,c$ are finite numbers, so for large enough prime $p_i>\max\{a,b,c\}$, the exponents are both zero.

If your infinite product notation is just an unfortunate mistake and you meant to use the correct canonical prime factorization, then you cannot assume that $a$, $b$ and $c$ all have same set of prime divisors.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I never claimed they can't both be zero in the general... My claim is that for each i, there are only two cases: either $a_i \neq b_i$, or $a_i = b_i$. Only in the case that $a_i \neq b_i$ am I claiming that they can't both be zero (obviously).
Hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: In that scenario, I am afraid your second case basically amounts to the entire problem. There almost certainly is a reason (I suspect very deep, algebraic number theory related) why an elementary attempt fails for a problem like this. Look also IMO 2007 B2, for another example.